# Maven manifest file issue

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I have been struggling with this for some time. I have a Maven project that builds and packages just fine with one problem. I have a jar I am using that is NOT in my companies version of NEXUS. I added the jar to my `.m2` repository through this command line command:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:/u/lib/terajdbc4-15.00.00.20.jar -DgroupId=com.teradata -DartifactId=terajdbc4 -Dversion=15.00.00.20 -Dpackaging=jar`

This jar will NOT append to the manifest file when the jar is built. So, when I need this jar, the code dies because it can't find the resource it's looking for (the teradata driver)

Is there any way to add this single jar to the manifest file IN ADDITION TO the other jars I'm already adding to the manifest?

Here is the build section from the parent pom file:

```
<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/Crunchify</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Crunchify/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>ap.invalert.handler.InvAlertHandler</mainClass>
                        </manifest>             
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path>          
                        </manifestEntries>                      
                    </archive>               
                    <finalName>Crunchify/Crunchify</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: If you have successfully "install"ed the file in the local repo at ~/.m2, you should look at the GAV (groupID, artifactID, version) and scope of your dependency. Maybe you are not specifying the installed JAR file's version correctly for the `maven-jar-plugin` to pick it up?

Comment: Why don't add this jar to your 3rd party lib in Nexus ?

Comment: Kedar Mhaswade - thanks.  I had the tag <scope>jar</scope> in my dependencies for this jar, and it prevented the jar definition from being written to the manifest.